# MATLAB-typeset command within LaTeX paragraph

Tags: matlab

I would like to know if there is a way to include a MATLAB command within a sentence in LaTeX such that the command is in the MATLAB typeset format. I have seen examples using the matlab_prettifier package but that was for whole sections of code and no examples were given such that bits of code can be included within a normal sentence. I am describing a section of code for my thesis and I just need to include a single command within/in-line with one of my sentences.

Comment: Welcome! In this case you can include that command/code-segment in a `\verb|..|` environment and mention line numbers in the MATLAB code for the audience to follow the demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `\lstinline[style=Matlab-editor]{<command>}` to typeset commands inline with MATLAB editor style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{document}

An example of an inline command is \lstinline[style=Matlab-editor]{d = rand(n,1)}. More text

\end{document}
```

[image: inline matlab command]

Somehow, this confuses the code highlighting in many editors (including this site). Therefore I would recommend to define a command

```
\newcommand{\lstinlineMatlab}[1]{\lstinline[style=Matlab-editor]{#1}}
```

and use `\lstinlineMatlab{d = rand(n,1)}` instead.

Comment: Thanks! This works beautifully and even retains the code highlightings in overleaf :)

Comment: @JDS if this was helpfull, you can upvote and/or except the answer in the top left of this post (upwards arrow for upvote and checkmark for accept).

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I'm still a bit new to Stack Overflow